# Apache POI ,unable to set fixed cell width of ms word table

Tags: apache-poi

When a long text is placed inside the individual cells of the apache poi ms word table, the width of the cell increases .according to the documentation I have added the below code

```
CTTblLayoutType type = table.getCTTbl().getTblPr().addNewTblLayout();
type.setType(STTblLayoutType.FIXED);
```

but I am getting the following issue:

```
 NoSuchMethodError: No interface method find_attribute_user(Ljavax/xml/namespace/QName;)Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/impl/values/TypeStoreUser; in class Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/impl/values/TypeStore; or its super classes (declaration of 'org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.TypeStore' appears in /data/app/in.tricta.pdfapplication-pngPxMsm4N7urOJRqp36PA==/base.apk!classes3.dex)
```

Comment: What version of Apache XMLBeans are you using?

Comment: i am using the poishadow-all.jar file .How can i find the version XMLBeans inside?

Comment: That's not an official Apache POI jar, so hard to say... where did you get that jar from? And would it be hard to just switch to using the official Apache POI jars?

Comment: The library was already inside a project.I tried the official Apache POI  4.1.0.but i was unable to create a document file using that.

Comment: If you want help with the official Apache POI jars, post the details of your problem after the upgrade. Otherwise, you will need to seek support from whoever in your company built that non-standard un-official jar...

Comment: I have downloaded and integrated all the jar file in poi 4.1.2.but i am unable to build the project due to lots of duplicate class like                                                                                          Duplicate class com.sun.xml.bind.Locatable found in modules jaxb-core-2.3.0.1.jar (jaxb-core-2.3.0.1.jar) and jaxb-impl-2.3.2.jar (jaxb-impl-2.3.2.jar)                                     Duplicate class com.sun.xml.bind.Messages found in modules jaxb-core-2.3.0.1.jar (jaxb-core-2.3.0.1.jar) and jaxb-impl-2.3.2.jar (jaxb-impl-2.3.2.jar)

Comment: See http://poi.apache.org/components/#components for the list of the dependencies of the various Apache POI components. jaxb isn't one of them...

Comment: it occurred when files such as commons-codec-1.13 from 4.1.2 was integrated .without which NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljavax/xml/stream/XMLStreamReader error occured